# Is there a way to programmatically list all of the available actions for an AWS service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am looking for a way to list all of the actions that can be used in a AWS IAM policy.

This is an example policy that uses IAM actions:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1457442845000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreatePolicy",
                "iam:CreatePolicyVersion",
                "iam:GetGroupPolicy",
                "iam:CreateGroup",
                "iam:GetPolicy",
                "iam:GetPolicyVersion",
                "iam:GetRolePolicy",
                "iam:ListAttachedGroupPolicies"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to search through actions from a file, and for that I would like to have all the available actions. I could not find a way yet to get that list. Any direction is appreciated.

Comment: I maintain https://github.com/TryTryAgain/aws-iam-actions-list/blob/master/all-actions.txt which gets updated every 4 hours ;) I often simply grep with some regex to find things I need.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Amazon provides a policy generator which it self, knows all of the possible APIs and Actions at the current point in time.

One can generate a list of Actions from the AWS Policy Generator `policies.js`:

```sh
curl --header 'Connection: keep-alive' \
     --header 'Pragma: no-cache' \
     --header 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
     --header 'Accept: */*' \
     --header 'Referer: https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html' \
     --header 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
     --silent \
     --compressed \
     'https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/js/policies.js' |
    cut -d= -f2 |
    jq -r '.serviceMap[] | .StringPrefix as $prefix | .Actions[] | "\($prefix):\(.)"' |
    sort |
    uniq
```

Comment: I get `--silent`, but why have the other curl options? It works for me without them.

Comment: @IainSamuelMcLeanElder the AWS endpoint isn't intended for general use, so they probably made it really prissy about who is calling it. Essentially the headers make curl pretend to be the JS app.

Comment: @IainSamuelMcLeanElder I just checked, and like you suspected, the headers are irrelevant :)

Answer (score 10):

I liked Trentium answer, but it will need maintenance.

I think I will use the [AWS Policy Generator](https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html) call for the [policies.js](https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/js/policies.js) file

Comment: With respect to requiring maintenance, *any* point in time query of the AWS service actions or IAM policy actions will require constant maintenance.  AWS is constantly enhancing their services, and thus new actions are being added all the time.  I have seen this on multiple occasions, eg with Athena and QuickSight, in which over the course of a few weeks, new service actions have become available.  Keeping an eye on these changes is particularly necessary if the IAM or Orgs policies are configured to ALLOW by default and DENY by exception.

Comment: Let's hope that AWS maintains the policies.js file for us!

Comment: @IainSamuelMcLeanElder they do, I hope they continue to too... I maintain the project https://github.com/TryTryAgain/aws-iam-actions-list/commits/master that looks for updates every 4 hours and as you can see from that commit history they update those services/actions constantly. I like following along, even being able to learn about things before they make it to a blog post...fun around re:Invent time :D

Answer (score 5):

The available actions for each service are in the documentation for those services, for example the list of IAM actions is in the [IAM documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_Operations.html), and the list of EC2 actions is in the [EC2 documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_Operations.html).

Comment: one may also get them from going into the IAM console and creating a policy. That's a nice way to know if it's "ListBucket" or "ListBuckets". (answer: yes. both.)

Comment: Not all policies exist in the IAM namespace. Things that define policies on the resource itself like S3 or ECR are really hard to find more than a general allow everything policy example.

Comment: @btilford it is hard to find good examples of resource level policies, but the acceptable fields are all documented under that specific service's documentation. The IAM link I gave is to the IAM specific actions. I didn't say all policies are a available there, I said this is where all the IAM service actions are documented, and you can look at the other services to see the list of their actions.

Comment: There's an easier spot to find a reference to all actions available in the IAM reference page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_actions-resources-contextkeys.html

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same issue, except was looking for Actions associated with more than just AWS Service IAM.  Solved by:

- Pulling the AWS SDK for Javascript ( see https://sdk.amazonaws.com/builder/js/ ) for all services.
- Loading the resulting minified javascript file ( aws-sdk-2.680.0.min.js ) as part of a small custom HTML document.
- Writing a javascript function that takes the desired service, and loops through the object `AWS.apiLoader.services[ 'iam' ][ Version ].operations`, pulling the list of Actions.  ( Note that 'Version' is in the format of `yyyy-mm-dd` and in the minified javascript file, there was only one entry for each AWS service. )
- Exporting the results.

Hope someone finds this helpful, as this was the only way I was able to programmatically get a comprehensive list of the Actions associated with an AWS Service...

Comment: I accept this until I find a better way. Thanks!

Comment: @Istvan, I appreciate the upvote, but since the time that I wrote my response, I believe Adam's recent response regarding the `policies.js` file is more accurate and simpler.  In fact, back in Aug 2020 during an engagement with AWS engineering, they provided me the `policies.js` link referred by Adam, as a simpler alternative which contains all the service action policies available.  (As a minor aside, the `policies.js` file is ever so slightly different than the service actions APIs, as there are a sprinkling of IAM policies, e.g. `codecommit:GitPull`, which are IAM policies, but not APIs...)

Comment: Yes, I think  his code is great too. Thanks @Trentium.

Comment: Interesting discussion, with the help of a fellow dev and AWS enthusiast, created 2 Lambda functions to pull this off.

https://github.com/cloudframeworks/aws-api

1. getServiceNames will return all valid service names, sorted.
2. getServiceActions will return all valid service actions for a provided service name, sorted.

We took it a step further and created an API Gateway HTTP API, linked the routes to the two functions and can now just make a quick API call to get the service actions.

Does anyone know if AWS regularly updates that policies.js file hosted on their S3 bucket?

Comment: @NJITman, we still use the API builder to enumerate the AWS service-actions, but predominantly rely on the policies.js file to vet our custom IAM role policies.  Per my comment just above, it was AWS engineering that pointed us to the policies.js file as an alternative.  We continually find new service-actions and new IAM permission-only-actions in the policies.js file as AWS expands their services.  (Note that the API builder will not include the IAM permission-only-actions, such as 'iam:PassRole' or 'codecommit:GitPull', and hence the policies.js file is more comprehensive.)

Answer (score 2):

I was pretty annoyed that there is no easy way to do this, so I built a python utility tool that takes the data from `https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/js/policies.js` and translates it into a python dictionary.  It also handles caching of the file locally so running the command doesn't take too long after running it once.

Easy way to get a list:

```
pip install pyiamvortex
pyiamvortex get-aws-actions
```

ref:

- https://pypi.org/project/pyiamvortex/
- https://github.com/nbajoel/pyiamvortex

Answer (score 1):

Lists of all actions available for each service are available in the IAM Reference Documentation here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_actions-resources-contextkeys.html

Actions, Resources and applicable Conditions are defined.

Comment: This is the only official source as far as I can tell. I was about to write a scraper for these pages until I saw the solution using policies.js.

Comment: Someone did write a scraper so we don't have to! See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75950418/111424) for details.

Answer (score 1):

If you have node installed on your machine, simply type `npx get-aws-actions` in  your terminal. No need to install anything. This npx command fetches the actions from the AWS policy generator file `https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/js/policies.js` and support text search to pinpoint the actions for specific AWS services (e.g., search for `s3:` to list all the S3 actions).

Answer (score 1):

Fluggo's [service authorization reference scraper](https://github.com/fluggo/aws-service-auth-reference) is a machine readable version of the official [Service Authorization Reference documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_actions-resources-contextkeys.html).

The GitHub repo history shows an audit trail of policy changes.

Here's an example of how to use it.

Save the auth reference.

```bash
curl \
--silent \
--show-error \
--url 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fluggo/aws-service-auth-reference/master/service-auth.json' \
> /tmp/auth.json
```

Search for IAM actions ending in "Role".

```bash
cat /tmp/auth.json \
| jq --raw-output '
  .[]
  | {service: .servicePrefix} + (.actions[] | {action: .name})
  | select(.service == "iam" and (.action | match("Role$")))
  | "\(.service):\(.action)"
'
```

Output:

```
iam:CreateRole
iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole
iam:DeleteRole
iam:DeleteServiceLinkedRole
iam:GetRole
iam:ListInstanceProfilesForRole
iam:PassRole
iam:TagRole
iam:UntagRole
iam:UpdateRole
```

I used this to discover that allowing `iam:*Role` isn't a good way to allow all lifecycle actions on a normal role because it allows things like `CreateServiceLinkedRole` and `PassRole`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding my comment as an answer as well. I currently maintain the project https://github.com/TryTryAgain/aws-iam-actions-list

It checks the policies.js file mentioned in other answers here but also "announces" New Services and things like that. Fun to peruse commits https://github.com/TryTryAgain/aws-iam-actions-list/commits/master during AWS re:Invent time or if you're waiting for a particular IAM action to be added/released :)

https://github.com/TryTryAgain/aws-iam-actions-list/blob/master/all-actions.txt contains a full list of all known IAM actions from that policies file listed in alphabetical order; from within the last 4 hours, based on that policies.js file. You can then use regex filters against that all-actions.txt file to quickly find particular things you may be interested in as well. Please feel free to open up any issues or comment back here with suggestions.

For example, to get all actions for the new "Q" service:

`grep ^q:.* all-actions.txt`

or for getting back all EC2 actions that contain "Ingress" or "Egress":

`grep -E "^ec2:.*Ingress|Egress.*" all-actions.txt`